# socket.io.js file on the net

Tags: node.js

I want to use socket.io.js from a kind of external cdn and not from my own server.
I found the http://cdn.socket.io/stable/socket.io.js file, but the newer version
build:0.8.7 i cant find on the net.

does anybody know a link to that version?

Comment: Remember that you need to serve Socket.IO from the server you're connecting to.  Otherwise, communications won't work, due to cross-domain restrictions.

Comment: Brad: This is incorrect. The domain is restricted to the domain the JavaScript is evaluated on, not the one it is served from.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here you can find 0.9.5. http://www.cdnjs.com/#/search/socket.io